# spoolsv.exe CPU issues on new server

Tags: cpu-usage, windows-server-2022

Similar to @Tomviv's post 1117360, but I can't comment or message the user who raised it as this is a new account for the sake of this issue.

We installed a new DC Server for a client hosting 2 print share queues. I am familiar with Print Nightmare and have deployed printers before on multiple networks by enabling point and print settings and I have allowed drivers to be installed from the specified server FQDN and IP.

It appears to be completely random, but the spoolsv.exe ends up consuming all the remaining CPU to max to 100%. It even seems to happen overnight now even when the printers are not in use which makes absolutely no sense. I stop the service and restart the server and I can monitor the performance all day with little to no disruption, but in the morning the CPU is maxed again from the spool service.

I have enabled the print event logs but I don't find any identifying errors.

What is also similar to @Tomviv's post (1117360) is that these are Konica Minolta printers using the universal driver PCL6 v4. This appears to be the only driver that works and is straight from the manufacturer.

the printers are:
BizHub C257i
BizHub C360i

I do notice that these printers are not specified in the INF file directly. I don't know enough about INF files to know if that is part of the issue or if I can edit it in some way.

What I also notice is that, at times, the system idle process states there is free CPU resource (example 40%) but the CPU is showing as at 100%.

I have tried SFC and DISM health checks. I have tried AV scans. I have tried replacing the drivers with alternate versions but they say they are "not compatible with print sharing". I have tried emptying the PRINTERS folder (C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS), but it is often even empty even when the issue is evident.

Happy to provide more info if needed. Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks
Aa